# Average operation on signed signals in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I'm trying to calculate the average of a signal on 4 consecutive values. This signal is signed and I'm really not sure about the right calculation to do.

```
SIGNAL my_signed_signal : std_logic_vector(15 DOWNTO 0) := (OTHERS => '0');
SIGNAL average_sum      : signed(17 DOWNTO 0) := (OTHERS => '0');
SIGNAL average_result   : signed(15 DOWNTO 0) := (OTHERS => '0');

...

-- within my process

average_sum <= average_sum + signed(my_signed_signal); -- loop 4 times

...

average_result <= average_sum(17 DOWNTO 2);   -- how I finally get the result (div by 4)
```

I am aware that this should work for unsigned signals but I'm pretty sure it doesn't for signed ones because of the signed bit. Yet I don't really know what to change. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: My VHDL exceedingly rusty but I believe sign extension should take place automatically given the types involved. Alternatively you could bias the values into the unsigned range by inverting the MSB of the inputs, then unbias the unsigned result into the signed range by again inverting the MSB. This is equivalent to adding 0x8000 to the inputs and subtracting 0x8000*4 on output to undo the offset.

Comment: The answer ought to be in the `numeric_std` library where you can examine the definitions of the `+` operators.

Comment: There's nothing I can see that looks wrong from the snippet you have supplied. If you want to make sure that the addition was working on same size vectors then you can use the "resize()" function which does sign extension on signed types i.e. 
`resize(signed(my_signed_signal),average_sum'length)`
Be aware that you will need to reset average_sum in between the 4 clock calculations. The truncation will also leave you with a half-bit negative bias in the result.
A full example would help to see if the issue is in the rest of the code.

Comment: Thank you for your replies, I'll try the resize function !

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it works for `signed` types, too.